# Merge code of same operation with two different conditions

Tags: if-statement, merge

I have a question. I'm trying to tidy up some coding.
I have this part of code

```
        if (self.type == self.BETAECM):
        for line in contentInfo:
            if line.startswith("caid:"):
                caid = self.readEcmInfo(line)
                if "x" in caid:
                    idx = caid.index("x")
                    caid = caid[(idx + 1):]
                    caid = caid[:4]
                    caid = caid.upper()
                    if (caid >= "1700") and (caid <= "17FF"):
                        return True
            elif line.startswith("====="):
                caid = self.readCaid(line)                        
                if "x" in caid:
                    idx = caid.index("x")
                    caid = caid[(idx + 1):]
                    caid = caid[:4]
                    caid = caid.upper()
                    if (caid >= "1700") and (caid <= "17FF"):
                        return True
        return False
```

As you can see there are two different conditions that are handled with the same operation 
I want to tidy up everything so that the identical parts of the code (what starts with if "x" in caid) are only written once. Is this possible?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know this language, but I'll take a stab at it.

```
for line in contentInfo:
  caid = "nothing"
  if line.startswith("caid:"):
    caid = self.readEcmInfo(line)
  elif line.startswith("====="):
    caid = self.readCaid(line)                        
  if "x" in caid:
    idx = caid.index("x")
    caid = caid[(idx + 1):]
    caid = caid[:4]
    caid = caid.upper()
    if (caid >= "1700") and (caid <= "17FF"):
      return True
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, it's python!

Comment: New problem, I have this error:     if "x" in caid:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'caid' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0):

You need to join them using an OR operator. In other words you what one condition OR the other to be true in order to excecute your code.

`if line.startswith("caid:") || line.startswith("====="):`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it too!

Comment: Sorry, my answer is wrong, didn't see there was a different statement on each. @Beta 's one is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you soooo much!
What I was missing is that the last if statement (if "x" in caid:) had to go on the same level the previous one. It works now!

So if I want to merge another example:

```
def readEcmInfo(self, line):
    if ":" in line:
        idx = line.index(":")
        line = line[(idx + 1):]
        line = line.replace("\n", "")
        while line.startswith(" "):
            line = line[1:]
        while line.endswith(" "):
            line = line[:-1]
        return line
    else:
        return ""
    elif "CaID" in line:
        idx = line.index("D")
        line = line[(idx + 1):]
        line = line.replace("\n", "")
        while line.startswith(" "):
            line = line[1:]
        while line.endswith(" "):
            line = line[:-1]
        return line
    else:
        return ""
```

Should it go like this?

```
def readEcmInfo(self, line):
    if ":" in line:
        idx = line.index(":")
        line = line[(idx + 1):]
        line = line.replace("\n", "")
    elif "CaID" in line:
        idx = line.index("D")
        line = line[(idx + 1):]
        line = line.replace("\n", "")
    while line.startswith(" "):
        line = line[1:]
    while line.endswith(" "):
        line = line[:-1]
        return line
    else:
        return ""
```

Comment: I don't see how control can reach that first `elif`. And one question per question, please.